# Android no such table Exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I started a new Project. Here I want to save Data to my Database but for some reason I always get this Exception. Hope you  could help me.
Maybe it's important to know that all this runs in an Fragment.

```
04-04 20:06:39.535  20756-20756/de.company.packageE/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: trailinfo
04-04 20:06:39.625  20756-20756/de.company.packageE/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting startzeit=1428170497482 ort_lat=47.8563527 ort_lng=11.8006212
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: trailinfo (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO trailinfo(startzeit,ort_lat,ort_lng) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:892)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:503)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1568)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1440)
            at de.work4dogs.TheMantrailingApp.RecordTrailFragment.trackingStart(RecordTrailFragment.java:213)
            at de.work4dogs.TheMantrailingApp.RecordTrailFragment.onClick(RecordTrailFragment.java:268)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My DBHelper looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import de.company.package.TrailContract.TrailInfo;

public class TrailInfoDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "trail.db";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TRAILINFO = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TrailInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            TrailInfo._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_SUCHHUND + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_AUSLEGEZEIT + " LONG," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_STARTZEIT + " LONG," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ENDZEIT + " LONG," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ADRESSE + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ORT_LAT + " DOUBLE," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ORT_LNG + " DOUBLE," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_RUNNER + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BEGLEITPERSON + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TRAILLEGER + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TRAILLEGER_DETAILS + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_GERUCHSTRAEGER + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_GERUCHSTRAEGER_DETAILS + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ABGANG + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UMGEBUNG + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_WITTERUNG + " INTEGER," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TEMPERATUR + " INTEGER," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BODEN + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UEBUNGSSCHWERPUNKTE + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UEBUNGSSCHWERPUNKTE_DETAILS + " TEXT," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_SCHWERPUNKT_BEWAELTIGT + " INTEGER," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_MOTIVATION_DES_HUNDES + " REAL," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TEAMARBEIT + " REAL," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BLIND + " INTEGER," +
            TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_LAENGE + " DOUBLE" +
            " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TrailInfo.TABLE_NAME;

    public TrailInfoDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TRAILINFO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

And at least here I want to interact with the Database:

```
TrailInfoDbHelper dbTrailInfoHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbTrailInfo;         // DB for Trail Info

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        dbTrailInfoHelper = new TrailInfoDbHelper(getActivity());
        dbTrailInfo = dbTrailInfoHelper.getWritableDatabase();      // WritableDatabase for the TrailInfo

    }

private void trackingStart() {

        // Getting start Values for new Trail
        long startTime = c.getTime().getTime();        // The Time when the Trail was started

        // Write the Data into ContentValue
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TrailInfo.COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_STARTZEIT, startTime);

        // Store Data in Database and recieve the TrailID
        Id = dbTrailInfo.insert(TrailInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New ID: " + String.valueOf(trailId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

The Code where all statics are defined

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class TrailContract {

    public TrailContract() {}

    public static abstract class TrailPoints implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trailpoints";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILPOINTS_TRAILID = "trailid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILPOINTS_TIME = "time";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILPOINTS_LAT = "lat";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILPOINTS_LNG = "lng";
    }

    public static abstract class TrailInfo implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trailinfo";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_SUCHHUND = "suchhund";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_AUSLEGEZEIT = "auslegezeit";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_STARTZEIT = "startzeit";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ENDZEIT = "endzeit";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ADRESSE = "adresse";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ORT_LAT = "ort_lat";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ORT_LNG = "ort_lng";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_RUNNER = "runner";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BEGLEITPERSON = "begleitperson";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TRAILLEGER = "trailleger";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TRAILLEGER_DETAILS = "trailleger_details";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_GERUCHSTRAEGER = "geruchstraeger";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_GERUCHSTRAEGER_DETAILS = "geruchstraeger_details";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_ABGANG = "abgang";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UMGEBUNG = "umgebung";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_WITTERUNG = "witterung";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TEMPERATUR = "temperatur";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BODEN = "boden";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UEBUNGSSCHWERPUNKTE = "uebungsschwerpunkte";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_UEBUNGSSCHWERPUNKTE_DETAILS = "uebungsschwerpunkte_details";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_SCHWERPUNKT_BEWAELTIGT = "schwerpunkt_bewaeltigt";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_MOTIVATION_DES_HUNDES = "motivation_des_hundes";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_TEAMARBEIT = "teamarbeit";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_BLIND = "blind";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TRAILINFO_LAENGE = "laenge";
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried any solution from other similar questions?

Comment: I posted the code where it defined above @Der Golem

Comment: @Selvin Yes, I tried all solutions I found but none of them worked

Comment: `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` ... i don't think so ... also write what have you tried to fix it ... similar question are asked 10 times a week

Comment: I tried to fix it by increasing the DATABASE_VERSION, with reinstalling the App and with initialising the Database in the Activity. But When I'm right the Database is not created, because OnCreate() is not called

Comment: Is there nobady to help me?